# redirect the error to results within org src

Tags: emacs, org-mode, org-babel

I am writing a demonstrate some errors reported within org src

```
#+begin_src ipython :session alinbx :results output
11 / 0
#+end_src
```

It report `ZeroDivisionError` in a fresh buffer

```
ZeroDivisionErrorTraceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-184a5c9f162a> in <module>
      1 # report
----> 2 11 / 0

ZeroDivisionError: division by zero
```

The errors then be manually copied to the org as a results to demonstrate.

How could redirect to errors to results as `&> a_file` does?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at John Kitchin's post:

https://kitchingroup.cheme.cmu.edu/blog/2014/12/21/Capturing-stderr-from-Python-in-org-mode-take-2/